# How do I calculate the gravitational force exerted by a thin ring of uniform mass M?

Tags: physics, applications

I'm working on a problem and can't seem to get it.

Find the gravitational force exerted by a thin uniform ring of mass *M* and radius *a* on a particle of mass *m* lying on a line perpendicular to the ring through its center. Assume *m* is at a distance *y* from the center of the ring.

I'm going to assume the center of the ring is the origin and the particle is at the point (0, y).  Due to symmetry we can ignore the gravitational force in the x direction.  It's the y-component of the force that is throwing me off.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a ring (two radii) or can it be viewed as a circle (the one-dimensional object)?

Comment: It can be viewed as a circle.

Comment: Then it is the attraction  by a mass of $M$ at distance $\sqrt{y^2+a^2}$. We could do it by integration, but we would be integrating a constant, so there is no reason to do it that way.

Comment: That's what I have in my notes but I'm unable to see why this is the case.  The reasoning escapes me.

Comment: What exactly do the notes claim?  They could be wrong.

Comment: I did this problem many years ago for a calc 2 class.  I have $\Delta F = \frac{G m \Delta M}{a^2 + y^2}$ directed along the hypotenuse.  Then I find the y-component.  I ended up with $F = \frac{G m M y}{(a^2+y^2)^{1.5}}$

Comment: In the meantime I posted an answer, the same as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force exerted by a small arc of angular width $d\theta$ is, by the Inverse Square Law, equal to $km\frac{M}{2\pi}\frac{1}{y^2+a^2}\,d\theta$, where $k$ is a constant. Integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$. We get $\frac{kmM}{y^2+a^2}$. For the component in the $y$-direction, multiply by $\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+a^2}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This is what I have in my notes when I did the problem years ago.  Right now I don't see why each small arc of angular width $\Delta \theta$ can be considered to be $y^2+a^2$ distance from the particle.

Comment: @YequalsX draw the whole thing. $y^2+a^2$ is the distance from any point in the ring to the mass.

Comment: The distance, by the Pythagorean Theorem, is $\sqrt{y^2+a^2}$. Take the inverse square, we get $\frac{1}{y^2+a^2}$.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 I must be daft because I've drawn this and stared at it for a while and don't see this.  Take the differential portion at point (0, a).  The distance of that point on the ring to the the mass at (0, y) is not $y^2 + a^2$.  That distance is $y - a$.

Comment: @YequalsX I screwed up, see André's comment.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 André's comment is not helpful to me because clearly I'm not seeing why each differential arc can be considered to be $\sqrt{y^2 + a^2}$ distance from the point mass.  It's as if each differential arc can be considered to be at (a, 0) and I don't see why this is the case.  The point mass is at (0, y).  Only two points on the ring are a distance $\sqrt{y^2 + a^2}$ from the point mass.

Comment: This is a three-dimensional problem. The particle is on a line perpendicular to the entire _plane_ that the ring lies upon. So you do not have a particle at $(0,y)$ and a piece of the ring at $(0,a)$. If the particle is at $(0,y,0)$ (in three dimensional space!) then the ring needs to be parallel to the $x,z$ plane--might as well put it _on_ the $x,z$ plane, so $(a,0,0)$ is a point on the ring and so is $(0,0,a)$, but the ring's $y$-component is always zero. _Now_ apply Pythagoras.

Comment: @YequalsX $\sqrt{y^2+a^2}$ is not the measure of the differential arc, it's the distance from any point of the ring to the mass! $d\theta$ is the infinitesimal angular width.

Comment: @David K  Thank you!  Now I see.  I interpreted the problem as a 2 dimensional one.  Your explanation clears everything up.